# Python 3.8 IDLE refuses to save, CTRL+S produces a line break

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

See title. Can't run scripts either because it complains that it isn't saved, and if I go to save it nothing happens. CTRL+S produces a line break. Happened all of a sudden, worked fine before this

If I use "save as" or CTRL+SHIFT+S it allows me to select the file but then nothing happens

Comment: Make sure you are running the latest 3.8.6.  In 3.8.4 and 3.8.5 IDLE has a bug related to saving files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Make sure you have IDLE classic windows selected in settings > keys]

Make sure you have IDLE classic windows selected in settings > keys